# How would a neutral hydrogen gas interact with a relativistic spacecraft?

Tags: special-relativity, radiation, space-travel

Inspired by a discussion from the comment thread of a gaming youtube video, I've been thinking about what kind of radiation environment a relativistic spacecraft would be exposed to as it passes through the interstellar medium.

I don't really have the background to analyze the effects of radiation on equipment or the human body properly, but I've been thinking about interactions with ionized gases as basically an intense cosmic ray flux. However, I don't know how to treat neutral gases.

To that end, what would a neutral hydrogen gas "look like" to an observer moving relativistically through it, and what kinds of effects would the gas have on the observer? Would it still "look" neutral, or would it interact with the observer as if it were ionized? That is, would it act like a stream of charged particles with respect to its effects on equipment and health? Could we deflect it electromagnetically?

For reference, I have a good undergrad background in relativity and in nonrelativistic quantum mechanics, but very little useful background in QED, particle physics, or anything focused on radiation as a hazard.

Comment: How does a mosquito interact with your windshield?

Comment: @JonCuster Poorly. I should specify, though, I'm not talking about a dense gas. I'm talking about the interstellar medium, and even if the answer is splat I'd love a little more than that :P.

Comment: @JonCuster Back of the napkin and provided I haven't made a mistake, the particle flux you'd experience moving 0.3c through an interstellar medium of 1 proton/cm^3 is on the order of 10^9cm-2s-1. By comparison, the particle flux you'd experience as a mosquito passing through a pane of glass at 70 mph is around 10^26cm^-2s-1, if your glass is mostly silicon. Not exactly analogous.

Comment: If you have a good background in relativity, then you should acknowledge that the 4-current is a vector. Hence, charge density transforms with $\gamma$, but $\rho=0=\rho'$.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape I'm not sure that this applies clearly to my question -- sure, the classical, macroscopic picture of a continuous and vanishing charge density would seem to make the question of charge trivial. But that's not really a complete picture -- classically we'd like to imagine that this macroscopically uniform charge density is really made up of a bunch of discrete, nonzero point charges. Since I'm more concerned with the effects of, say, each individual impact with a hydrogen atom, I think the microscopic picture becomes relevant.

Comment: Enter quantum electrodynamics, which I do not know. The answer seems decidedly against the hydrogen looking ionized in the nonrelativistic QM picture. I'm not decided what it looks like in the microscopic, relativistic classical picture (though I'm currently leaning against). But I'm quite wary of taking either of those pictures as an accurate model for a relativistic, microscopic system.

Answer (score 2):

There is a famous xkcd on this: [Relativistic Baseball](https://what-if.xkcd.com/1/).

This is at atmospheric pressure. Suppose you tried something similar, except with an atmosphere 1000000 times less dense. The pitch would have to travel 1000000 times farther to encounter the same amount of air. The result would be pretty much the the same though.

Comment: This was an interesting read, thank you! However, I would think the more relevant quantity would be the flux, and in that respect the density of the gas very much makes a difference. I would expect a much less cataclysmic fate for our intrepid space explorers.